# Decision tree with undefined set + output probabilities

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

Imagine you have type of data/columns like **country**, **product_type**, **status**. Where **status** is target/leaf node.

Then you have data like

1: *Germany* | *XBox* | *No Sale*

2: *UK*      | *PS4* | *Sale*

Now we'll build decision tree upon these data, where root is Country, then Product and Status is leaf.

Finally here comes my question, what if tree ask you for Country and you say "Belgium", or something undefined, then tree mark this answer as undefined and ask for product and you answer "PS4" and tree will tell you that status Sale has 50% and No Sale has 50%. Or what if you ask for undefined data-sequence like Germany and then PS4 ?

Is there some special kind of Decision Trees or another structure/algorithm which will solve this problem ?

*Simple name will be enough, I'll google it.*

-- I'll work with 30-40 types of data / columns and around 4m journal data or 1m present data (rows). Maybe Decision Tree will be a madness for this purpose, not sure...

Answer (score 0):

This depends on *your* implementation.

You may choose to either return the most common answer (e.g. "No Sale", optionally with the appropriate frequencies!)
or to return "no answer" (= "no data"). Your application needs to be able to handle this case. Choose as needed for your use case and implement accordingly.

Comment: Returned values has to be probabilities. My idea is that "Sales Man" insert its current data and will see if he has a chance to have a Sale, then update some fields and check if probability for Sale is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Then implement your decision tree such that it returns probabilities! E.g. "90% no sale, 10% sale."

Comment: That is just *counting*, no computation required.